# PostgreSQL - GROUP_CONCAT for JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, group-concat, jsonb

I try to find a way to concat JSONB values using Postgres.

For example I have two lines :

```
INSERT INTO "testConcat" ("id", "json_data", "groupID") 
VALUES (1, {"name": "JSON_name1", "value" : "Toto"}, 5);

INSERT INTO "testConcat" ("id", "json_data", "groupID") 
VALUES (2, {"name": "JSON_name2"}, 5);
```

I would like to do something like :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(json_data)
FROM testConcat
GROUP BY groupID
```

AND as results to obtain something like :

```
[{"name": "JSON_name1", "value": "Toto"}, {"name": "JSON_name2"}]
```

I try the creation of aggregate function, but when there is the same key into the JSON, then they are merged and only the last values is preserved :

```
DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS jsonb_merge(jsonb);

CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge(jsonb) (
    SFUNC = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
    STYPE = jsonb,
    INITCOND = '{}'
 );
```

When I use this function as here :

```
SELECT jsonb_merge(json_data)
FROM testConcat
GROUP BY groupID
```

The result is  :

```
{"name": "JSON_name2", "value": "Toto"}
```

And not as those that I want because the

```
{"name": "JSON_name1"}
```

is missing. The function preserve only the different keys and merge the other one with the last value.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would try simple way too - `SELECT ('['||string_agg(json_data::text,',')||']')::jsonb FROM temp."testConcat" GROUP BY "groupID"`. This gives you jsonb in format you want. Function `jsonb_agg` seems to convert original jsonb parts into texts...

Comment: `with t(x) as (values('{"name": "JSON_name1"}'::jsonb),('{"name": "JSON_name2"}')) select jsonb_agg(x) from t;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is always only a single key/value pair in the JSON document, you can do this without a custom aggregate function:

```
SELECT groupid, jsonb_object_agg(k,v order by id)
FROM testconcat, jsonb_each(json_data) as x(k,v)
group by groupid;
```

The "last" value is defined by the ordering on the `id` column

The custom aggregate function might be faster though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I try it, but it seems that the result is not corresponding to this that I am searching for. When I have 2 lines with the same keys, but differents values I would like to preserve all this differences.

Comment: @Vicking: can you extend your sample data in the question to also show that?

Comment: I change the question's description. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The expected result `[{"name": "JSON_name1", "value": "Toto"}, {"name": "JSON_name2"}]` is a simple `select jsonb_agg(json_data) from testconcat`

Answer (score 3):

Finally I just find a solution, even if it is not the best, it seems to works.

I create the agreate function, as previously described with a small modification :

```
DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS jsonb_merge(jsonb);

CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge(jsonb) (
   SFUNC = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
   STYPE = jsonb,
   INITCOND = '[]'
);
```

I just replace :

```
INITCOND = '{}'
```

with

```
INITCOND = '[]'
```

And after used it as previously :

```
SELECT jsonb_merge(json_data)
FROM testConcat
GROUP BY groupID
```